# SQL statement ignored for a index nested loop join

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to build a data warehouse based on a star schema with 5 dimension tables and 1 facts table using two sets of data, `MASTERDATA` which holds 100 records and `DATASTREAM` which holds 10,000 records.

I am reading 100 records from `DATASTREAM` as an input into a cursor then reading the cursor record by record and then retrieving the relevant records from `MASTERDATA` on the index `product_id` as a index nested loop join. After this I am loading the new attributes from the transaction tuple inside the relevant dimension and fact tables.

However, I have a few errors. I'm just looking for help to understand why I am getting the errors I am getting. The errors at the moment are:

```
Error(98,6):PL/SQL:SQL Statement Ignored
Error(101,5):PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(105,8):PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:  if
Error(113):PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:  ;
```

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE transactionINLJ AS TYPE t_cursor is ref cursor;
v_cursor t_cursor;
v_cursor_records DATASTREAM%rowtype;
record_100 varchar2(300);
rec number;

v_customer_id masterdata.customer_id%type;
v_customer_account_type masterdata.customer_account_type%type;
v_product_id masterdata.product_id%type;
v_product_name masterdata.product_name%type;
v_supplier_id masterdata.supplier_id%type;
v_supplier_name masterdata.supplier_name%type;
v_outlet_id masterdata.outlet_id%type;
v_outlet_name masterdata.outlet_name%type;
v_sale_price masterdata.sale_price%type;

t_customer_id int;
t_supplier_id int;
t_product_id int;
t_outlet_id int;
t_date_id int;
t_sales_fact int;

BEGIN
    rec := 1;
    WHILE (rec <= 10000)
    LOOP
        record_100 := 'SELECT * FROM datastream WHERE datastream_id between '|| TO_CHAR(rec) ||
        ' and ' || TO_CHAR(rec+99);
        OPEN v_cursor FOR record_100;
            LOOP
                FETCH v_cursor INTO v_cursor_records;
                EXIT WHEN v_cursor%notfound;
                
                SELECT product_id, product_name, supplier_id, supplier_name, sale_price
                INTO v_product_id, v_product_name, v_supplier_id, v_supplier_name, v_sale_price
                FROM masterdata
                WHERE product_id = v_cursor_records.product_id;
                
                SELECT COUNT(0)
                INTO t_product_id
                FROM product_dim
                WHERE product_id = v_cursor_records.product_id;
                IF t_product_id = 0 THEN 
                    INSERT INTO product_dim(product_id, product_name)
                    VALUES (v_cursor_records.product_id, v_cursor_records.product_name);
                END IF;
                
                SELECT COUNT(0)
                INTO t_customer_id
                FROM customer_dim
                WHERE customer_id = v_cursor_records.customer_id;
                IF t_customer_id = 0 THEN 
                    INSERT INTO customer_dim(customer_id, customer_name,customer_account_type)
                    VALUES (v_cursor_records.customer_name, v_cursor_records.customer_account_type, v_cursor_records.customer_account_type);
                END IF;
                
                SELECT COUNT(0)
                INTO t_supplier_id
                FROM supplier_dim
                WHERE supplier_id = v_cursor_records.supplier_id;
                IF t_supplier_id = 0 THEN 
                    INSERT INTO supplier_dim(supplier_id, supplier_name)
                    VALUES (v_cursor_records.supplier_id, v_cursor_records.supplier_name);
                END IF;
                
                SELECT COUNT(0)
                INTO t_outlet_id
                FROM outlet_dim
                WHERE outlet_id = v_cursor_records.outlet_id;
                IF t_outlet_id = 0 THEN 
                    INSERT INTO outlet_dim(outlet_id, outlet_name)
                    VALUES (v_cursor_records.outlet_id, v_cursor_records.outlet_name);
                END IF;
                
                SELECT COUNT(0)
                INTO t_date_id
                FROM date_dim
                WHERE d_date = v_cursor_records.d_date;
                IF t_date_id = 0 THEN 
                    INSERT INTO date_dim(d_date, d_year, d_quater, d_month, d_day)
                    VALUES (v_cursor_records.d_date
                            ,EXTRACT(year FROM v_cursor_records.d_date), TO_CHAR(v_cursor_records.d_date,'Q')
                            ,EXTRACT(month FROM v_cursor_records.d_date)
                            ,EXTRACT(day FROM v_cursor_records.d_date));
                END IF;
                
                SELECT COUNT(0)
                INTO t_sales_fact
                FROM sales_fact
                WHERE product_id = v_cursor_records.product_id
                AND customer_id = v_csr_rec.customer_id
                AND supplier_id = v_csr_rec.supplier_id
                AND outlet_id = v_csr_rec.outlet_id
                AND d_date = v_csr_rec.d_date
                AND sale_price = v_csr_rec.sale_price
                AND quantity_sold = v_csr_rec.quantity_sold;
                IF t_sales_fact = 0 THEN 
                    INSERT INTO sales_fact(customer_id,product_id,outlet_id,supplier_id,d_date,sale_price,total_sale,quantity_sold)
                    VALUES (v_cursor_records.customer_id, v_cursor_records.product_id, v_cursor_records.outlet_id,v_cursor_records.supplier_id,
                        v_cursor_records.d_date, v_cursor_records.sale_price, v_cursor_records.quantity_sold*sale_price, v_cursor_records.quantity_sold)
                END IF;
                
                COMMIT;
                
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE v_cursor;
        COMMIT;
        
        rec := rec+100;
        
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: The last `INSERT INTO` statement is missing a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed this mistake and a few others after reading through my code again, but now I have a bit more errors such as: PLS00302: component "PRODUCT_NAME" must be declared. Would you know why this component is not declared?

Comment: Maybe the column MASTER_DATA.PRODUCT_NAME doesn't exist, or it exists in a different schema, or your user doesn't have direct access to it. But you might want to start over and try building a minimum viable procedure instead of building everything and then debugging all the errors.

Comment: By the way, the cursor doesn't need to be dynamic. With a static cursor you could switch to the simpler `for r in (select...) loop` syntax which would simplify the code somewhat. Also those counts for every value on every row are inefficient, if performance is a concern. And although it won't make any difference, why `count(0)` and not the standard `count(*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an unfortunate truth that occasionally procedural processing is required. But almost all this can be done with just SQL and a tiny bit of PL/SQL extensions. In particular there is no need to "select count..." for any of your target tables, sql handles that quite easily on the INSERT statement itself. Further there is no need to loop through a cursor on a row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) process, instead use BULK COLLECT and FORALL to handle the entire array (100 rows in this case) all with a single INSERT for each table. With it there is no need to for loop control counters, nor calculating the ID numbers to retrieve,  nor the exact the number of rows (what would happen if your source table contained 10050 or 9950 rows instead of exactly 10000). As a side effect you gain considerable performance.  The following shows that process:

```
create or replace procedure transactioninlj as 
 
    k_bulk_buffer_size constant integer := 100;
   
    cursor v_cursor is
           select d.customer_id
                , d.outlet_id
                , d.outlet_name
                , d.customer_name  
                , d.customer_account_type
                , d.d_date
                , d.quantity_sold
                , m.product_id
                , m.product_name
                , m.supplier_id
                , m.supplier_name
                , m.sale_price
             from datastream d
             join masterdata m on m.product_id = d.product_id
         ;
    type t_cursor_records is table of v_cursor%rowtype;
    v_cursor_records t_cursor_records;

begin
    open v_cursor; 
    loop
        fetch v_cursor
         bulk collect
         into v_cursor_records
        limit k_bulk_buffer_size; 
        
        forall v_index in 1 .. v_cursor_records.count 
           insert into product_dim(product_id, product_name) 
           select v_cursor_records(v_index).product_id
                , v_cursor_records(v_index).product_name 
             from dual
            where not exists 
                 ( select null 
                     from product_dim
                    where product_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).product_id
                  );
                  
        forall v_index in 1 .. v_cursor_records.count 
           insert into supplier_dim(supplier_id, supplier_name)
           select v_cursor_records(v_index).supplier_id
                 , v_cursor_records(v_index).supplier_name
              from dual
            where not exists 
                 ( select null 
                     from supplier_dim
                    where supplier_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).supplier_id
                  ); 
        
        forall v_index in 1 .. v_cursor_records.count
           insert into customer_dim(customer_id, customer_name,customer_account_type)
              select v_cursor_records(v_index).customer_id
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).customer_name
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).customer_account_type 
                from dual
            where not exists 
                 ( select null 
                     from customer_dim
                    where customer_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).customer_id
                  );  
                  
        forall v_index in 1 .. v_cursor_records.count
           insert into outlet_dim(outlet_id, outlet_name)
              select v_cursor_records(v_index).outlet_id
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).outlet_name 
                from dual
            where not exists 
                 ( select null 
                     from outlet_dim
                    where outlet_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).outlet_id
                  ); 
                  
        forall v_index in 1 .. v_cursor_records.count
           insert into date_dim(d_date, d_year, d_quater, d_month, d_day)
              select v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date
                   , extract(year from v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date)
                   , to_char(v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date,'Q')
                   , extract(month from v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date)
                   , extract(day from v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date)
                from dual
            where not exists 
                 ( select null 
                     from outlet_dim
                    where  outlet_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).outlet_id
                  );                  
 
        forall v_index in 1 .. v_cursor_records.count
           insert into sales_fact( customer_id
                                 , product_id
                                 , outlet_id
                                 , supplier_id
                                 , d_date
                                 , sale_price
                                 , total_sale
                                 , quantity_sold
                                 )
              select v_cursor_records(v_index).customer_id
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).product_id
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).outlet_id
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).supplier_id 
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).sale_price
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).quantity_sold
                     * v_cursor_records(v_index).sale_price
                   , v_cursor_records(v_index).quantity_sold
               from dual
              where not exists 
                  ( select null 
                      from sales_fact
                     where product_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).product_id
                       and customer_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).customer_id
                       and supplier_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).supplier_id
                       and outlet_id = v_cursor_records(v_index).outlet_id
                       and d_date = v_cursor_records(v_index).d_date
                       and sale_price = v_cursor_records(v_index).sale_price
                       and quantity_sold = v_cursor_records(v_index).quantity_sold
                  );
                  
       exit when v_cursor_records.count < k_bulk_buffer_size;              

    end loop; 
 
    close v_cursor;    
    commit;
    
end  transactioninlj;
```

Note: The DDL for the source tables is not included in your post so I had to "invent" the definition for DATASTREAM. However, you only have 2 source inputs: DATASTREAM and MASTERDATA. Since you only select 5 columns from masterdata, every thing else must come from datastream.